# Trying to sanitize very basic MySQL SELECT in Python/Django

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, parameterized-query

This is driving my nuts.  I have this very basic query that works without the sanitization statement but breaks with it.  Everything I've read says to do it this way.

```
query = "SELECT COL1 FROM A_TABLE %s"
queryUserInput = "WHERE COL1 = 'user input value'"
cursor.execute(query, (queryUserInput,))
```

I receive the error:

> 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' WHERE ...
>
> Top of the stack:
>   C:..\env\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py in
>   cmd_query
>
> raw_as_string=raw_as_string)

Python 3.7
Django 2.1.3

Any advice is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Parameterisation is supposed to used to santitise a variable value which is being used to form part of the finished SQL - e.g. the `7` in a query such as `SELECT * FROM user WHERE ID = 7`. You can't parameterise a whole section of SQL the way you're doing - and indeed there should be no need to do so.

I don't know Python specifically, but logically I think your code should be:

```
query = "SELECT COL1 FROM A_TABLE WHERE COL1 = %s"
queryUserInput = "user input value"
cursor.execute(query, (queryUserInput,))
```

in order that it only parameterises the actual user input, and not any of the SQL.

(Your original code would produce a SQL string something like `SELECT COL1 FROM A_TABLE 'WHERE COL1 = \'user input value\''` which clearly is not valid SQL at all, due to everything after A_TABLE being contained within a string literal.)

This documentation (of the execute() method) shows you some other examples of correct usage: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

Answer (score 1):

you can try it:

```
queryUserInput = "user input value"
cursor.execute("SELECT COL1 FROM A_TABLE WHERE COL1 = %s", [queryUserInput])
```

and django doc:

[Executing custom SQL directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)